# How make UILabel with autoresizingMask in a custom cell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uilabel, autoresize

I have a custom uitableviewcell with several labels and I would like for some of them to autoresize their frame (width) based on the content (text). I am not sure how to accomplish that. I tried to set fixed frame of the label and after apply autoresizingMask, but that doesn't do the trick. Any *pointer to a sample?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following method:

```
CGSize *size = [label.text sizeWithFont:fontOfLabelText];
float widthOfLabel = size.width;
```

size.width will return the actual width that the text in the label will occupy on the screen. Set the label width equal to width of text.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to adjust the frame of a label to fit the labels text, just call

```
[label sizeToFit];
```

This will fit in both dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make so that the label fits in multiple lines, you have to say:

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

However I'm not sure if this is the one that you want... Usually if the content is text than that'll be what you want.